# Establishing Triangle Inequality of a particular norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Define $$\|f\|_1 := \left( \int_a^b |f|^2 + |f'|^2 dx\right)^{1/2} $$ where $f$ is $C[a,b]$. How do I show that $$ \|f + g\|_1 \le \|f\|_1 + \|g\|_1. $$

This is my attempt:

$$\|f + g\|_1^2 = \int_a^b (|f+g|^2 + |f'+g'|^2) dx  $$

Examining the right hand side: 
$$\int_a^b (|f+g|^2 + |f'+g'|^2) dx   \le \int_a^b (|f| + |g|)^2 dx +\int_a^b (|f'| + |g'|)^2 $$
$$= \int_a^b|f|^2 dx + \int_a^b|g|^2  dx+\int_a^b 2|f||g|dx + \int_a^b|f'|^2 dx+ \int_a^b|g'|^2 dx+ \int_a^b2 |f'||g'|dx
$$

This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, also in its integral form?

Comment: @LutzL Yes. I know that, but how do I apply that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

For $a,b \ge 0$, you have $\sqrt{a+b} \le \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ and $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is increasing.

Comment: does this help in finishing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As usual with a norm related to a scalar product in a real vector space, you prove
\begin{align}
\|a+b\|^2&=⟨ a+b,a+b⟩\\&=\|a\|^2+2·⟨ a,b⟩+\|b\|^2\\
&\le\|a\|^2+2·\|a\|·\|b\|+\|b\|^2\\&=(\|a\|+\|b\|)^2
\end{align}